# How can I achieve a gap in a border around a LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, border, android-linearlayout

I want to have a gap in a border which is around a LinearLayout. In this gap there should be text.

I think the image explains it very well:

[image]

Is this possible? I know how to create a border around the Layout but not how to do this gap with the text. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `my_drawable.xml` file in your project's `res/drawable` folder:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke 
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000066" />  
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
  <solid 
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</shape>
```

After it you can add it as a background for a `LinearLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"  <!-- Or whatever you want -->
        android:layout_height="200dp"  <!-- Or whatever you want -->
        android:background="@drawable/my_drawable">
        </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```